# How to auto publish images and news from email straight to a front-end portal?

Tags: nodes, emails

I'm working for a daily newspaper with a news portal built on Drupal.

They require a way through which newsmen in the field can send images and news content to an email address. That image and content is to e auto-published straight to front-end of the portal.

Any suggestions about how to do so in Drupal?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [mailhandler](http://drupal.org/project/mailhandler) module for this. This would create a content from the mail send to an email ID

> Mailhandler takes mail (usually from an IMAP mailbox) and imports it
>   as whatever type of content you choose. Plug-in modules allow you to
>   do more awesome things like post comments, select different
>   authentication methods, and set properties such as published / sticky
>   status using "commands". Hugely powerful and flexible, but includes a
>   "quick-start" module to help get you started.